# Symfony Forms - entity field with query_builder, no choices_as_values?

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I am trying to achieve something very simple but not sure if this is supported, possible or unexpected behaviour. I have a Symfony entity field which loads some data based on the selection of another field. The data is loaded ok but I want the option name and value to be the same. At the moment, it is populating the names ok, but I want the values to be the same as the names (the choices_as_values option in a Symfony choice field). Is that possible in an entity field.

Here is an example code:

```
    $builder
        ->addEventListener(
            Form\FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
            function (Form\FormEvent $event) {
                $attributeData = $event->getData();

                $event->getForm()->add(
                    'group',
                    'entity',
                        array(
                        'class'         => 'AppBundle:CategoryAttributeData',
                        'placeholder'   => 'Select a data group',
                        'label'         => 'Attribute Group',
                        'choice_label'  => 'content',
                        'required'      => false,
                        'query_builder' => function (Repository\CategoryAttributeData $repository) use ($attributeData) {
                            $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                ->select('u')
                                ->where('u.type = :type')
                                ->andWhere('u.group IS NULL')
                                ->setParameter('type', $attributeData->getType())
                            ;

                            return $queryBuilder;
                        }
                    )
                );
            }
        )
    ;
```

The output is:

```
<select id="attribute_data_group" name="attribute_data[group]" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select a data group</option>
<option value="1">Cars</option>
<option value="2">Electronics</option>
<option value="3">Furniture</option>
</select>
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
<select id="attribute_data_group" name="attribute_data[group]" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select a data group</option>
<option value="Cars">Cars</option>
<option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
<option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
</select>
```

Since this field is populated via an event listener (because it depends on another field value) I cannot add a view transformer in here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually more complicated than it would seem on the surface. The `Entity` form type assumes that the "values" of the choice selector are the unique identifier for an entity, this allows the form type (and its associated transformers) to find and transform the passed values from and to the relevant entities. So the first question is - can you uniquely identify your entity by the string "Cars", or "Electronics"? If you can't, then the next question is how were you planning on converting that string into the entity?

If you can, then things are relatively easier. Effectively you need to provide a different `ChoiceList` implementation for the choice field type - this is effectively what the `Entity` type already does. I'm not familiar with the correct way to do this and I believe the method changed between Symfony 2.6 and 2.7, but I would look into classes like `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType` as well as the base `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType`.

Short version: it's not wholly straightforward but definitely possible.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't thought of that case being such a complication. My idea was to load the values for a given select box from the database and the most logical (at that point in time) option was via an entity field. The actual database schema doesn't reference the value by its id (foreign key) but rather just saves the selected value as text. I guess the better option in the case would be to use a choice field, define the form type as a service, inject the repository and load up a choice_list with the results from a query from the repo, right?

Comment: SO SIMPLE thing - populate choices from database into FORM. What is point of that to make it SO COMPLICATED?????? after symfony 4.4 this project (symfony) is a mess what you have to do for simple tasks "beyond" the straight forward things...

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the option 'choice_value', for example:

```
'choice_value' => function (?Team $team) {
     return $team ? $team->getBesoccerId() : '';
}
```

It's 100% compatible with the 'query_builder' option. Continuing the same example:

```
->add('team', EntityType::class, array(
     'class' => Team::class,
     'label' => 'Equipo',
     'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($lang) {
                          return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                            ->andWhere('t.besoccerId IS NOT NULL')
                            ->andWhere('i18n.cod_lang = :cod_lang')
                            ->setParameter('cod_lang', $lang)
                            ->leftJoin('t.translations', 'i18n')
                            ->orderBy('t.sort', 'ASC');
                    },
     'choice_label' => 'name',
     'choice_value' => function (?Team $team) {
                         return $team ? $team->getBesoccerId() : '';
                    }
))
```

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-value).